# Sortable List in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to create a VBA user interface that will allow user to order items? See example image taken from a pdf editor.

[image: sample]

I want my users to be able to order data in a popout window or list and output their order to a different location. Data is a list of buildings.

Thanks!

Comment: So far, I tried a work around where I have the user select from a list (data validation) for each point (1st, 2nd, 3rd) and generate an error if they have a duplicate. Would like to get a bit more advanced if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this solution I used a `UserForm` with a `ListBox` and a `SpinButton` control.

I put a list of cells I wanted in my listbox in Column A of Sheet1.  I have a generic `Building 1`, `Building 2`, etc. through `Building 19` so that my data is contained in the range `A1:A19` of `Sheet1`.  This is arbitrary and you should change to suit your needs.

This code basically stores the original `RowSource` that contains the items in the `ListBox`, deletes the `RowSource` from the `ListBox`, rearranges the underlying source data and then re-applies the `RowSource` to the `ListBox` in the new order after the user clicks either up or down on the `SpinButton`

I did not change the default control names (`UserForm1`, `SpinButton1`, `ListBox1`).

1. Open the VB Editor (either Developer tab --> Visual Basic or press <kbd>ALT+F11</kbd>
2. Right click Microsoft Excel Objects --> Insert --> UserForm
   [image]
3. Add a `SpinButton` and a `ListBox` so the UserForm looks like so
   [image]
4. In the VB Editor, right click `UserForm1` under Forms --> View Code
5. Paste the following code in

   ```
   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

       'Populate the UserForm with data from range A1:A19 (arbitrary, change to suit your needs
       ListBox1.RowSource = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("A1"), Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Address

   End Sub

   Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()

       With ListBox1
               If .ListIndex = .ListCount - 1 Then Exit Sub 'No item selected or we are in the last position
              lCurrentListIndex = .ListIndex + 1 'Get the current position of the item
              strRowSource = .RowSource 'Get the current row source
              strAddress = Range(strRowSource).Address 'Address of the row source range
              strSheetName = Range(strRowSource).Parent.Name 'Grab the parent sheet name
              .RowSource = vbNullString 'Empty the listbox

              'Re-arrange the underlying data
              With Range(strRowSource)
               .Rows(lCurrentListIndex).Cut
               .Rows(lCurrentListIndex + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
              End With

              'Re-apply the row source
              .RowSource = strRowSource

              'For continuity, select the previously selected element in its new position
              .Selected(lCurrentListIndex) = True
       End With

   End Sub

   Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
         Dim lCurrentListIndex As Long
         Dim strRowSource As String
         Dim strAddress As String
         Dim strSheetName As String

         With ListBox1
               If .ListIndex < 1 Then Exit Sub 'No item selected or we are in the first position
              lCurrentListIndex = .ListIndex + 1
              strRowSource = .RowSource
              strAddress = Range(strRowSource).Address
              strSheetName = Range(strRowSource).Parent.Name
              .RowSource = vbNullString

              With Range(strRowSource)
               .Rows(lCurrentListIndex).Cut
               .Rows(lCurrentListIndex - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
              End With

              .RowSource = strRowSource
              .Selected(lCurrentListIndex - 2) = True

       End With
   End Sub
   ```

I tried to add comments to clarify what I am doing.  It is a slightly cumbersome method, and was adapted from code available [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/listbox-up-down.htm).  If you click the Debug (looks like play) button the form should display and populate with the values of cells A1:A19 of Sheet1.  You can then select an item in the `ListBox` and press the up or down buttons of the `SpinButton` in order to move items up or down the list.  An important assumption is that `MultiSelect` **is disabled** on this `ListBox`.

Ordinarily I would not post such an in-depth solution without seeing what you tried, but this problem piqued my curiosity.

Comment: Thanks!  If you don't mind clicking the green check to accept this as an answer I'd appreciate it.  Helps with the points so people know I am at least somewhat reputable :).  Happy coding!